# Do we really need to upgrade .NET framework to .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have created multiple Azure function apps using .NET Framework 4.6 Do i really need to upgrade them to .NET core

What if i don't upgrade is it going to effect function apps in future ?

Are we going to have .Net framework in future ?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the latest major .NET Framework release will be it. In future we'll have .NET 5.

Comment: *.net framework* isn't going to die any time soon, there is like nearly 20 years of code written it. however, *.net 5/6* is the way of the future, you are missing out on all the BCL and future goodness if you stick with framework

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions only v1 supports .NET Framework. `Version 1.x is in maintenance mode and only supports development in the Azure portal or locally on Windows computers. Enhancements are provided only in later versions.`